# Who is the original author of this simple paradoxical decomposition?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

Paradoxical decompositions of sets usually require the axiom of choice; Hausdorff or Banach-Tarski are well-known examples. A paradoxical decomposition of a point set without the axiom of choice has been constructed by [Sierpinski and Mazurkiewicz](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30001.1-2-8.shtml). A set $S$ is the union of two sets $A$ and $B$. When the elements of $A$ are rotated ($\rho$) by one radian, then $\rho$$A = S$, and when the elements of $B$ are translated ($\tau$) by one unit, then $\tau$$B = S$ too.

There is a simple variant. Decompose the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers into $A$, the set of even integers, and $B$, the set of odd integers. When the elements of $A$ are divided $(\delta)$ by 2, then $\delta$$A = \mathbb{Z}$. When the elements of $B$ are translated by one unit (in positive or negative direction) and then divided by 2, then $\delta\tau$$B = \mathbb{Z}$.

Same can be shown for other sets $S$, for instance the set of positive integers (then $B$ must be translated by +1).

My question: Have these paradoxical decompositions already appeared in literature? I would like to include them into my lectures with appropriate quotation but could not yet find a source or an author.

Comment: See the "infinitely many guests" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel . Of course this is well-documented.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I know Hilbert's hotel, but I miss the idea of a paradoxical decomposition of a set.

Comment: Hausdorff in his original construction used that type of decompositions --- the axiom of choice applied after. I am not sure if it was known before Hausdorff (Grand Hotel was formulated in 1924 after Hausdorff's 1914).

Comment: Hausdorff in his paper (Math. Ann. 75, 1914) did not hint to the AC (introduced in 1904), but it is necessary for this kind of decomposition.

Comment: @RhettButler  "did not hint" does not mean "did not use".

Comment: I can't believe that Cantor was not aware of this when introducing infinite cardinals around 1875, and most likely this was already well-known.

Comment: In the Banach-Tarski paradox the AC is only used to translate (in the ordinary sense) the paradoxal decomposition of the free group on two elements (that does not require AC and is very explicit and very much like your decomposition of the integers) to a paradoxical decompostion  of a space (a solid sphere in R^3 say) on which the group acts. The latter 'feels' more paradoxical because of the distance preserving property of the group action. Intuitively distance preserving maps should preserve measure. The decompostion of the group as an abstract object doesn't feel paradoxical at all.

Comment: What I mean is: people would probably not talk a lot very explicitly about paradoxical decompostions of sets if there weren't examples of sets that intuitively cary some sense of size that should be preserved by the action, but (by the paradox) apparently isn't. The example of Hilbert's hotel is interesting in that respect. The fact that every integer is   half of some even integer is not really interesting, until you reformulate it in terms of size: are there more integers than even integers, or just as many? Only now it becomes paradoxical.

Comment: @Anton Patrunin: See the first sentence of my question, please.

Comment: @ YCor: Cantor was fully aware of the bijection between integers and even integers, already before he invented the term cardinal number in 1886,  but he did not use this for paradoxical decompositions of point sets. Nonmeasurable sets were first shown by Vitali, then by Hausdorff.

Comment: @RhettButler Here is my claim: the idea in your construction is presented in Hausdorff's paper which is 1914 and I do not know earlier refs.

Comment: @Anton Patrunin: Hausdorff's disadvantage: His proof requires AC.  His advantage: His set, the surface of the unit sphere, is spatially bounded. Same with Banach-Tarski. Sierpinski and Mazurkiewicz get by without AC, alas their set is not spatially bounded. The idea in my question is of the same kind: Unbounded set, no AC required. I don't know whether this idea merits mentioning in literature. That's why I ask whether someone has seen it.

Comment: For the Banach-Tarski paradox, we are talking about objects which support not just a notion of size, but *finite size*, and manipulating parts of them with *size-preserving transformations*. This seems crucially different to the various examples attributed to Galileo, Hilbert, Cantor, etc. where the "sizes" are either infinite, or the transformations involved do not preserve size. I don't see what the fuss is about in this question (there is more than one sense of "more than", which resolves the "paradox" mentioned by Vincent), and IMHO this question is not appropriate for MO.

Comment: @RhettButler, did you read Hausdorff? On the level of ideas everything is there. (I do not know an earlier ref and I do not know when Sierpinski and Mazurkiewicz wrote on this topic.)

Comment: @ Anton Petrunin: Of course I read Hausdorff in the German orginal: http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~subtypo3/gdz/pdf/PPN235181684_0075/PPN235181684_0075___LOG_0033.pdf Mazurkiewics, born in 1888, was a student when he found the paradox. So I guess it was about simultaneously with Hausdorff 1914, As I said: Hausdorff and BT need AC. This is a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but the reference may be interesting nonetheless. Paradoxical decompositions of sets are discussed in the very beginning of Stan Wagon's book "The Banach-Tarski paradox", Cambridge University Press, 1985 (very recommendable, lots of paradoxes, nice for lectures). The following is a nice quote from the first paragraph of the first chapter:

> In a famous example, Galileo observed that the set of positive integers can be put into a one-one correspondence with the set of square integers, even though the set of non-squares, and hence the set of all integers, seems more numerous than the squares.

Ok, this is slightly different from the Hilbert hotel situation, but the basic idea seems to appear as early as 1638. 
The more general statement (Wagon calls it "the modern version of Galileo's observation") appears as Theorem 1.4 of Wagon's book: a set $X$ is paradoxical with respect to the action of its permutation group if and only if it is infinite. 
Unfortunately, the exact history of this result is not discussed in Wagon's book (the name Tarski appears, though). The if direction requires the axiom of choice (but not for cardinals).

Comment: Thank you, I also read Stan Wagon's book which is certainly the standard source for this topic, in particular if the reader is not fluent in French. And I looked into a lot of other literature, but could not find the crucial idea $A\cup B$ = $\mathbb{Z}$ and simultaneously, after applying operators according to the idea of  Sierpinski and Mazurkiewicz, $A' = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B' = \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore I asked here. But I will not yet give up. Perhaps there will be an expert on history here around who has come across the source on some old conference proceedings or lessons.